# Spring Batch Admin Integration to DB2 throwing SqlIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: spring, configuration, admin

I am trying to integrate Spring batch admin to existing spring batch program. This runs fine with hsqldb, but when we configure it to DB2 it throws SqlIntegrityConstraintViolationException. Db2 tables were already created in the DB2 with the default script provided in the admin jar.

We are using quartz scheduler to trigger the jobs.

**Here is the exception trace**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into OD1.ABC_BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID, JOB_INSTANCE_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, VERSION, CREATE_TIME, LAST_UPDATED, JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; AN UPDATE, INSERT, OR SET VALUE IS NULL, BUT THE OBJECT COLUMN *N CANNOT CONTAIN NULL VALUES. SQLCODE=-407, SQLSTATE=23502, DRIVER=3.62.56; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlIntegrityConstraintViolationException: AN UPDATE, INSERT, OR SET VALUE IS NULL, BUT THE OBJECT COLUMN *N CANNOT CONTAIN NULL VALUES. SQLCODE=-407, SQLSTATE=23502, DRIVER=3.62.56
       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:249)
       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605)
       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:818)
       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:874)
       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:878)
       at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.saveJobExecution(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:157)
```

**Configuration is as follows**

```
#DB2 configuration
batch.job.jndi=jdbc/DBOMS
batch.tableprefix=OD1.ABC_BATCH_
batch.schema.script=
batch.drop.script=
batch.business.schema.script=
batch.database.incrementer.class=org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.DB2SequenceMaxValueIncrementer
batch.job.configuration.file.dir=target/config
batch.data.source.init=false
batch.job.service.reaper.interval=60000
batch.isolationlevel=ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED
batch.jdbc.testWhileIdle=false
batch.jdbc.validationQuery=
batch.database.incrementer.parent=sequenceIncrementerParent
batch.table.prefix=OD1.ABC_BATCH_
```

Comment: The error message says the insert into OD1.ABC_BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION contains a null value for a mandatory column. I don't know why it's referring to `COLUMN *N` instead  of the actual column name, but afaik there aren't than many mandatory columns in that table.

Answer (score 0):

We found the issue , We gave the table scripts to DBA. But DBA created the table to match the standards they follow and made it 
START_TIME TIMESTAMP NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT instead of START_TIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL. This is causing the issue, hope this helps someone.